# Функция поиска максимального элемента в массиве, ошибка segmentation fault

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Возникает ошибка segmantation fault, что может быть ее причиной?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxarray(void *base,
            unsigned long nel,
            unsigned long width,
            int (*compare)(void *a, void *b))
{
int max = 0;
int *w = (void*) base;
    for (int i = 0; i < nel; i+=width){
        if (compare (*(w+i) , max) > 0)
            max = *(w+i);
}
    return max;
}
#include <stdio.h>

int array[] = {
        10522,
        46150,
        30124,
        50155,
        20666
};

int compare(void *a, void *b)
{
        int va = *(int*)a;
        int vb = *(int*)b;
        if (va == vb) return 0;
        return va < vb ? -1 : 1;
}

int maxarray(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long,
        int (*)(void *a, void *b));

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("%d\n", maxarray(array, 5, sizeof(int), compare));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не по теме: `return va < vb ? -1 : 1;` — компаратор возвращает не единицу со знаком, а *лексикографической расстояние*; так что рекомендую заменить на 'return va - vb;' (заодно и случай равенства элементов корректно покроете).

Comment: Говорите, что будете передавать адреса в компаратор, а передаете значения. А бедный компилятор вынужден трактовать их как адреса и разыменовывать...

Comment: Дальше будет еще такая последовательность `int max = 0;` -> `if 
 compare (*(w+i) , max) > 0)` -> int vb = \*(int\*)b; -> segmantation fault

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Как я понимаю, вы хотели бы обобщить это сравнение, но реально вы этого не делаете. Например, откуда уверенность, что ваш максимум влезет в `int max = 0;`, а он например не типа `double`. Примерно такой же вопрос к `int *w = (void*) base;` В вашем коде таких противоречий несколько, и если вы хотели написать универсальный код, то его надо переделать, насколько мне кажется, если же просто найти самый большой элемент для конкретного случая - это можно сделать гораздо проще.

Comment: Действительно, `compare (*(w+i) , max)` - это некорректный код, на который компилятор будет вопить во все горло диагностическими сообщениями. А автор вопроса, как я понимаю, просто проигнорировал эти диагностические сообщения и решил, не разбираясь, спросить на форуме. Код формально некорректен, поэтому запускать его рановато.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
if (compare (*(w+i) , max) > 0)
               ^^^
```

из-за этого:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nel; i+=width){
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

Вы увеличиваете значение `i` на четыре (то есть `sizeof(int)`) за одну итерацию, будто `w` — это `char*`, и вы позднее приводите его к `int*`. На самом же деле `w` — это уже указатель на `int`. Поэтому вы отматываете не на четыре байта за раз, а на четыре *элемента* (то есть восемь байт), из-за чего быстро вылетаете за границы массива.

Замените строку:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nel; i+=width){
```

на

```
for (int i = 0; i < nel; i++){
```

и уберите `width` за ненадобностью.

Comment: Здесь только одно не совсем понятное место есть. Если мы так жестко прибиваемся к типу int, то наверное, стоит указатель base сделать также не void, а int, и убрать width, тогда все указанные выше проблемы исчезнут. В ином случае мы не сможем работать с чем-то, отличным по размеру от int'ов.

Comment: @Croessmah, это вопрос уже к автору кода.

Comment: Ну вообще-то авторский код выглядит как попытка общей *типонезависимой* реализации, по аналогии с `qsort` и `bsearch`. В такой ситуации советовать избавиться от `width` было бы неправильным. Правильным здесь будет объявить указатели не как `int *`, а как `char *`, т.е. перейти именно к *байтовой* адресной арифметике. Правильный подход приведен в ответах Croessmah и Alex, хотя там стоило бы также позаботиться о константной корректности - интерфейс функции тут по идее должен получится как у стандартной `bsearch`.

Comment: @Arhad я что-то пропустил? Потому что вот здесь **if (compare (\*(w+i) , max) > 0)** передаются значения, а не указатели. А вот здесь **int va = \*(int\*)a;** эти значения уже используются как указатели.

Comment: @tilin, и это тоже. Поэтому подал голос за закрытие вопроса как «Не по теме → Содержит опечатку».

Answer (score 3):

Приведу код, надеюсь, разберетесь:

```
void *maxarray(void *base,
            unsigned long nel,
            unsigned long width,
            int (*compare)(void *a, void *b))
{
    char *begin = base;
    char *max_ptr = begin;
    if (nel > 1) {
        char *cur = begin + width;
        char *end = begin + nel * width;
        for (; cur != end; cur += width) {            
            max_ptr = (compare(max_ptr, cur) < 0)? cur: max_ptr;
        }
    } else {
        if (nel == 0) {
            //error
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return max_ptr;
}
//usage:
printf("%d\n", *(int*)maxarray(array, 5, sizeof(int), compare));
```

Comment: Автора интересует, *почему* падает код. Ему неинтересны альтернативные реализации.

Comment: В его коде мешанина. Работаем с void*, но при этом жестко забиваемся на int. Отрицательные числа - тоже мимо. Почему его код падает ему уже Вы объяснили.

Comment: Солидарен с @Croessmah.

Answer (score 2):

Вот нормальный обобщенный (насколько это позволяет C) код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void * maxarray(void * base,
                unsigned int nelem,
                unsigned int width,
                int (*comp)(void*,void*))
{
    void * max = base;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < nelem; ++i)
        if (comp((unsigned char *)base + i*width,max) > 0)
            max = (unsigned char *)base + i*width;
    return max;
}

int array[] = {
    10522,
    46150,
    30124,
    50155,
    20666
};

int compare(void *a, void *b)
{
    int va = *(int*)a;
    int vb = *(int*)b;
    if (va == vb) return 0;
    return va < vb ? -1 : 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)maxarray(array, 5, sizeof(int), compare));
}
```

Результат *указывает* на максимальный элемент, не заботясь о его типе.

Answer (score 0):

Дальше будет еще такая последовательность

```
int max = 0;

if (compare (*(w+i) , max) > 0)

int vb = *(int*)b;
```

segmantation fault

замените

```
int compare(void *a, void *b)
```

на

```
int compare(int a, int b)
```

потому что вы передаете туда значения, а не указатели. Функция должна выглядеть так

```
int compare(int a, int b)
{
        if (a == b) return 0;
        return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}
```

И дополнительно в maxarray замените

```
for (int i = 0; i < nel; i+=width)
```

на

```
for(int i = 0; i < nel; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку уже нашли, приведу пример кода, который, по моему мнению, соответствует изначальной задумке автора. Проверял, работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxarray(void *base,
            unsigned long nel,
            int (*compare)(void* array, int a, int b))
{
    int max_pos = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nel; i+=1){
        if (compare(base, i, max_pos) > 0)
            max_pos = i;
    }
    return max_pos;
}

int array[] = {
        10522,
        46150,
        30124,
        50155,
        20666
};

int compare(void* array, int a_pos, int b_pos)
{
        int va = *(((int*)array) + a_pos);
        int vb = *(((int*)array) + b_pos);
        if (va == vb) return 0;
        return va < vb ? -1 : 1;
}

int maxarray(void*, unsigned long, int (*)(void *a, void *b));

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("%d\n", maxarray(array, 5, compare));
        return 0;
}
```